# CSS Javascript handle 2 event on 1 onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Code:

```
<a href="#" id="home" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">
    <li class="buttons">home</li>
</a>
<a href="#" id="user" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example2');return false;">
    <li class="buttons">users</li>
</a>
```

---

Java script:

```
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if ((document.getElementById(shID).style.display == 'none')||(document.getElementById(shID).style.display == '')) {
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
```

I want if click home, the example will appear and example2 will hidden and vice versa, can I do that?

Comment: ID must be unique. You have the same id for two elements.

Comment: Oh sorry, so I need to change the ID and ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a simplified approach, you can use the following function:

```
function showHide(shID) {
    // hide all divs
    var divIDs = ["example", "example2"];
    for (var i = 0; i < divIDs.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(divIDs[i]).style.display = 'none';
    }
    // show the one sent as argument
    document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Check a **[jsFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3LHNk/)**.

Comment: Oh I have more question regarding this, can i set the default content? like example become default, and later changing depend on click

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by default. Are you saying to a div keep opened between page loadings (if the user clicks on another link)?

Comment: Or.. if you want one to be loaded at the start, look at how the divs are defined: `<div id="example"  style="display: none">example</div>
<div id="example2" style="display: none">example2</div>`. Just remove the `style="display: none"` of the one you want as default. Such as here: http://jsfiddle.net/3LHNk/1/ (I removed from "example" .)

Comment: oh okay I figured it out, change the `style="display: none" > "block"` will do

Answer (score 0):

if you are using unique id's for the two elements you can achieve that by using the following code..

```
function showHide(shID) {
   var id = $(shID).attr("id");
   if(id == "example-show1")
   {
       $(example).show(1000);
       $(example1).hide(1000);
   }
   else if(id == "example-show2")
  {
       $(example1).show(1000);
       $(example).hide(1000);
  }
}
```

The above code was in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Jaavascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/6RQY3/1/

```
<script>
function showHide(shID) {
if(shID=="example")
{
shID2="example2";
}
else
{
shID2="example";
}
if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
  if ((document.getElementById(shID).style.display == 'none')||(document.getElementById(shID).style.display == '')) {
     document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById(shID2).style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
  }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jquery:

Your html:

```
 <a href="#" id="home" class="showLink" onclick="showHide(this);return false;"><li class="buttons">
        home
        </li></a>
        <a href="#" id="user" class="showLink" onclick="showHide(this);return false;"><li class="buttons">
        users
        </li></a>
```

And javascript:

```
function showHide(ele) {
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'home'){
      $('#example').show();
      $('#example2').hide();
    }
    else{
       $('#example').hide();
       $('#example2').show();
     }
}
```